# Enumerate all OWIN keys and values

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin, katana

How can you list out all OWIN keys and their values, similar to `Request.ServerVariables` in WebForms:

```
foreach(string k in Request.ServerVariables)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", k, Request.ServerVariables[k]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I would find this Googling but did not; the code is pretty straight forward after digging in with IntelliSense. It is based on `owinContext.Environment.Keys`

```
var owinContext = HttpContext.GetOwinContext();
foreach (string k in owinContext.Environment.Keys)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", k, owinContext.Environment[k]);
}
```